# Change configuration values post webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

In a static folder I have config.js

```
module.exports = {
  config: {
    urls: {
     auth: localhost
    }
  }
}
```

I run `npm run build` and send the output (dist folder) to the client to deploy in their production environment. I want the client to be able to edit the value of auth.

config is currently configured as a external file in webpack:

```
const config = require(path.join(paths.STATIC, 'config.js'))

externals: [{
    appsetting: JSON.stringify(config)
}]
```

How do I make config.js recognize changes post webpack build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this, using `axios`:

```
function readConfig () {
   return axios.get('./static/config.js').then((response) => {
       return response.data
   });
}

readConfig().then((config) => {
    // Do stuff
});
```

And make sure config.js is copied to the static/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Create an entry file in webpack.config for `config.js` and import/require `config.js` in other files where you consume the config.